# Is Embedded Unix/Linux on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Linux in particular is used in a whole lot of embedded applications.  What parts of those would be on topic here?

Comment: How do you tell embedded from ancient desktop, anyway ;-P

Answer (score 14):

I say yes, because the topic isn't really changing.  You're still talking about Unix/Linux, but just running them on an [embedded system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_computer).  As long as it doesn't steer towards programming the topic should be safe.  Just tag it embedded.

Answer (score 0):

I will say yes;   I contributed to a similar question with my take:

[Mac OS X: What's on topic?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/macosx-whats-on-topic)