# Are Mac OS specific questions allowed?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where exactly is the border between apple and UNIX](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/685/where-exactly-is-the-border-between-apple-and-unix)

Being that Mac OS X is based on FreeBSD, do questions about it fall into the scope of this site?