# question closed for off-topic, even though some answers here suggest it is not

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a sad record. First question asked in this site and it's been voted and closed for off-topic:

[Wrong timezone offset. How do I correct it? (help with zic timezone compiler)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62617/wrong-timezone-offset-how-do-i-correct-it)

A user, @[Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles), kindly enough pointed this thread out which suggests otherwise:
[Mac OS X: What's on topic?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/mac-os-x-whats-on-topic)

I have read the FAQ BEFORE posting and really thought, my question to be a good fit.
especially bullet list items 2 and 3:

> - The Unix foundation underlying MacOS (but generally not frontend application questions)
> - The underlying *nix OS on an embedded system or handheld device (e.g. an Android phone)

I'd like to understand the reason for closing the question. In order to avoid off-topicness of future questions.

Normally I would not challenge the votes to close, but I have genuinely no clue why the question is not Unix-related. It might well be my inexperience and failure to understand what Unix is. Either way I'd love to know and further educate myself.

Comment: Your question is open, and deservedly so.

Comment: Ah! very nice! Re-reading it all, I think I should have lead with "I need help with zic". That way I think I could have avoided the whole closing question business. I have a feeling of inadecuacy. Nearly 100% of the Unix & Linux questions are way over my head and this shows in the phrasing of the question which in turn hurts my chances of getting an answer. At least that's a current suspicion of mine. Could you help me out a bit?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything at all about Macs or ipods...